# Which direction does memory-mapped segment of a process's virtual address space grow by default?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

I'm currently going through the code that loads an ELF from disk to memory, which corresponds to the function [`load_elf_binary()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L823) in Linux kernel.

Such function sets up the addresses of different segments (e.g. text, data, bss, heap, stack, mmap'ed area). By tracing the code, I noticed one function: [`setup_new_exec()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L1014), which is defined [here in /fs/exec.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/fs/exec.c#L1433). Inside such function, it calls [`arch_pick_mmap_layout()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/fs/exec.c#L1438), which is defined [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/mm/util.c#L409). Note that I am not targeting a specific architecture like X86, so I am referring to the generic function definition.

Below is part of the code:

```
if (mmap_is_legacy(rlim_stack)) {
    mm->mmap_base = TASK_UNMAPPED_BASE + random_factor;
    mm->get_unmapped_area = arch_get_unmapped_area;
} else {
    mm->mmap_base = mmap_base(random_factor, rlim_stack);
    mm->get_unmapped_area = arch_get_unmapped_area_topdown;
}
```

Based on the code, I know there are two ways of obtaining the unmapped areas - bottom-up(legacy) and top-down. Such two ways are discussed in this [LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/91829/) as well.

To distinguish, we need [`mmap_is_legacy()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/mm/util.c#L370), which `return sysctl_legacy_va_layout;`. [`sysctl_legacy_va_layout`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/include/linux/mm.h#L84) is initialized to be 0 by default.

Does that mean by default, the memory mapped region of a process grows from top to bottom (from high address to low address; grows from the stack to the heap)?

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct. The layout presented in that LWN article is quite old though (it's a layout for old 32bit kernels), nowdays you will normally see `[HI] stack-> mmap-> <-heap elf [LO]`, or with legacy layout: `[HI] stack-> <-heap elf <-mmap [LO]`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli - Thanks for your reply! As you mentioned in your reply, the legacy layout nowadays has the mmap segment being the low address. Is there code that proves that? By checking the generic implementation, I did not see it. Besides, does the legacy memory layout nowadays start from virtual address 0?

Comment: This [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/509607/how-a-64-bit-process-virtual-address-space-is-divided-in-linux) is a good source that shows what layout virtual address space is on 64-bit architectures. I paste it here for reference. But I am a bit confused about the relationship between the layout discussed in the link and the memory layout of a process (.text, .data, .bss, heap, mmap, stack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general assumption that *"by default, the memory mapped region of a process grows from top to bottom"* is correct.

The default and legacy layouts nowadays should look like this:

```
DEFAULT               LEGACY
0xffffffffffffffff    0xffffffffffffffff   
    stack                 stack            
                                        
    mmap                  ...           
                                       
    ...                   heap             
    ...                   ELF
                         ...                
    heap                                
    ELF                   mmap
    ...                   ...
0x0000000000000000    0x0000000000000000
```

> [...] the legacy layout nowadays has the mmap segment being the low address. Is there code that proves that? Besides, does the legacy memory layout nowadays start from virtual address 0?

Sure, you can see this exactly in the code you linked, in the generic [`arch_pick_mmap_layout()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/mm/util.c#L409) implementation, which chooses a low `mmap_base` for the legacy layout. The calculation is `TASK_UNMAPPED_BASE + random_factor` (the `random_factor` comes from ASLR, see [`/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`](https://manned.org/proc.5)). Note that some architectures (namely x86, PA-RISC, PowerPC, S390, Sparc) override that function and provide their own, but the calculations that are done are pretty much the same (you can check the source code).

That `TASK_UNMAPPED_BASE` represents the lower boundary for the "mmap" virtual memory area, and it varies per architecture. It should not be defined as low as `0` (zero) though. It is usually defined in terms of `TASK_SIZE`.

Some examples:

- `TASK_SIZE / 3` = `0x2aaaaaaab000` on x86-64
- `TASK_SIZE / 3` = `0x40000000` on x86 32bit with default `VMSPLIT_3G` config
- `TASK_SIZE / 4` = `0x400000000000` on ARM64
- `CONFIG_PAGE_OFFSET / 3` = `0x40000000` on ARM 32bit with default `VMSPLIT_3G` config
- `TASK_SIZE / 3` = `0x5555555000` on MIPS 64bit with 40 VA bits
- `TASK_SIZE / 8 * 3` = `0x30000000` on PowerPC 8xx (32bit)

The lowest possible address mappable by userspace is actually [`/proc/sys/vm/mmap_min_addr`](https://wiki.debian.org/mmap_min_addr) and default *non-zero* (for example `0x10000` on x86). Such low addresses must be explicitly requested through an hint to `mmap`, they are not mapped voluntarily by the kernel as a result of `mmap(0, ...)`.

So we enstablished that for the legacy layout the "mmap" area starts at some low address, and we already know that the stack always starts at the highest address.

**As per the ELF itself**, the file is merely mapped in memory by the kernel according to its type and its program headers, usually contiguously with no holes, and the calculations are the same *regardless of default/legacy mmap layout*. You will see multiple segments mapped with different permissions as specified in the ELF program headers (see output of `readelf -l`), and those segments will contain different sections, such as `.text`, `.rodata`, `.bss`, and so on (see output of `readelf -S`).

For ELF *Executables* (i.e. `e_type` = `ET_EXEC`, see [`man 5 elf`](https://manned.org/elf.5)) the base virtual address is chosen by the ELF itself: it is fixed and determined at compile time, and such an ELF cannot be loaded at a different address in order for it to work.

For ELF *Shared Objects* (i.e. `e_type` = `ET_DYN`), which nowadays are the norm, the base virtual address is chosen by the kernel itself and is defined by [`ELF_ET_DYN_BASE`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/arch/x86/include/asm/elf.h#L253) (adjusted if ASLR is enabled). [This other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61561331/why-does-linux-favor-0x7f-mappings/61564602#61564602) covers x86. This value is *above* `TASK_UNMAPPED_BASE`, so you will see the ELF *above* the "mmap" area (higher addresses) in the legacy layout, and *below it* (lower addresses) in the default layout.

The "heap" area (a.k.a. the [program break](https://manned.org/brk.2)) by definition will start right after the ELF growing towards high addresses regardless.

---

Here's a couple of annotated screenshots (click to enlarge) to show what the default vs legacy layouts look like inspecting `/proc/[pid]/maps` on my x86-64 machine. *Note that low addresses are at the top*.

**Default**:

[image: default]

**Legacy**:

[image: legacy]